# Simple Tic-tac-toe in Python

Tags: python, beginner, game, tic-tac-toe

I am a beginner programmer who coded a simple Tic-tac-toe in Python for practice. Any feedback, especially regarding best practices and tidying up the code, is appreciated.

```
import random

board = {"a1": ".", "b1": ".", "c1": ".",
         "a2": ".", "b2": ".", "c2": ".",
         "a3": ".", "b3": ".", "c3": "."}
#randomly assigns user to either x or o
userIcon = random.choice(["x", "o"])
if userIcon == "x":
    computerIcon = "o"
else:
    computerIcon = "x"

def main():
    print("\n\nWelcome to Tic-tac-toe!\n")
    print("The columns and rows are labelled with letters and numbers respectively")
    print("Choose your desired spot by typing in the letter followed by the number and pressing Enter")
    print("For example: b2[Enter]\n")
    print(f"You {userIcon} will be playing against the computer ({computerIcon})")
    #the turn variable keeps track of whose turn it is (even number is user's turn, odd number is computer's turn)
    if userIcon == "x":
        print("Your turn is first")
        turn = 0
    else:
        print("Your turn is second")
        turn = 1
    input("\nPress Enter to start!\n")
    printBoard()
    #moves are made until the game is finished
    while True:
        if turn % 2 == 0:
            try:
                user()
                turn += 1
                printBoard()
                result = arbiter()
                if result != 0:
                    break
            except:
                print("Invalid")
                continue
        else:
            computer()
            turn += 1
            printBoard()
            result = arbiter()
            if result != 0:
                    break
    if result == 1:
        print("User wins")
    elif result == 2:
        print("Computer wins")
    else:
        print("Draw")

def printBoard():
    print("\n  a b c")
    for i in [1, 2, 3]:
        print(i, board[f"a{i}"], board[f"b{i}"], board[f"c{i}"], sep=" ")
    print("____________________________________")

#lets user make their move
def user():
        while True:
            selection = input("\nChoose your spot: ")
            if board[selection] != ".":
                print("Spot taken")
                continue
            else:
                board[selection] = userIcon
                break

#picks random available spot for computer
def computer():
    while True:
        row = random.choice(["1", "2", "3"])
        column = random.choice(["a", "b", "c"])
        if board[column + row] == ".":
            board[column + row] = computerIcon
            break

#returns 1 if user wins, 2 if computer wins, 3 if draw
def arbiter():
    if winner(userIcon) == True:
        return 1
    if winner(computerIcon) == True:
        return 2
    #checks for draw
    for i in board:
        if board[i] == ".":
            return 0
    return 3

#returns True if specified player has won, False if they have not won
def winner(icon):
    #check rows
    for i in [1, 2, 3]:
        line = 0
        for j in ["a", "b", "c"]:
            if board[f"{j}{i}"] == icon:
                line += 1
        if line == 3:
            return True
    #check columns
    for i in ["a", "b", "c"]:
        line = 0
        for j in [1, 2, 3]:
            if board[f"{i}{j}"] == icon:
                line += 1
        if line == 3:
            return True
    #check major diagonal
    line = 0
    for i in ["a1", "b2", "c3"]:
        if board[f"{i}"] == icon:
            line += 1
    if line == 3:
        return True
    #check minor diagonal
    line = 0
    for i in ["c1", "b2", "a3"]:
        if board[f"{i}"] == icon:
            line += 1
    if line == 3:
        return True
    return False

main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could represent the board as list of nine items, initialized as

```
board = ["."] * 9
```

Where, if `row` and `col` are zero-based coordinates, the respective index into `board` can be calculated as `row * 3 + col`. The indices of the board items are then placed like

```
0 1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8
```

This may need some rewrite but allows to define a function

```
def check_winner_seq(icon, start, step):
    for i in range(start, start + step * 3, step):
        if board[i] != icon:
            return False
        return True
```

To check a whole row, column or diagonal at once.

Then you can rewrite `winner` like

```
def winner(icon):
    # Check rows
    for i in range(0, 9, 3):
        if check_winner_seq(icon, i, 1):
            return True
    
    # Check cols
    for i in range(0, 3, 1):
        if check_winner_seq(icon, i, 3):
            return True
    
    # Check major diagonal
    if check_winner_seq(icon, 0, 4):
        return True
    
    # Check minor diagonal
    if check_winner_seq(icon, 2, 2):
        return True
    
    return False
```

With some advanced features like list comprehensions and the `all` and `any` functions, this can be written even more concise.